# How to "draw" pixels on the screen using assembly, and also how to take input from a user

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

So Ive been doing assembly programing for a little bit but there are some things I cant figure out how to do.
For example if I wanted to draw a black square in the middle of the screen, or even create a window how would I go about that?
All the graphical things are beyond me.

And as for my second question how do you take input from a user and use it in your code, like if I were making a calculator.

```
mov rax, (user picks a number)
mov rbx, (user picks another number)
sub rax, rbx
```

How could I take numbers that the person running the program types and use it for something like this?

Comment: In which environment (Windows, OSX, Linux; directX, metal, vulcan, X, wayland, ...)?

Comment: Im using linux.

Comment: You may write your program in C, get user input using C functions, then use inline assembler to play with calculations.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, and ill probably do it.
But if C is composed of assembly then why isn't there any user input in assembly?
Idk I'm no expert in how this works by any means.

Comment: For most modern OSs, talking to hardware (either input or output) is controlled by the operating system.  When means that when you want to call (say) printf, it calls a routine which calls a routine which calls another that eventually makes a call to the OS.  Yes, you can make that call yourself directly from asm, but there are going to be a number of frustrating limitations that C has already solved that you'll need to solve again.  About the fourth or fifth time you find yourself having to do that, you'll stop and ask yourself why you're doing that.  Use C where you can, asm where you must.

Comment: To get user input in Linux you can call `read` syscall ( https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/HEAD/constants/syscalls.md ) with file descriptor 0 ( which should be STDIN_FILENO, https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdout.3.html )